# Streamline this PHP snippet

Tags: php, foreach

I know this is a Wordpress based question, but I think the answer is definitely more stand-alone PHP.

On almost every site I do for a client I have to add some social media links, which come from an options page. I currently use this kind of snippet;

```
$twt = of_get_option('twitter');
$fcb = of_get_option('facebook');
$ins = of_get_option('instagram');
if ($twt) {
    echo '<li class="twitter"><a href="'.$twt.'">Twitter</a></li>';
}
if ($fcb) {
    echo '<li class="facebook"><a href="'.$fcb.'">Facebook</a></li>';
}
if ($ins) {
    echo '<li class="instagram"><a href="'.$ins.'">Instagram</a></li>';
}
```

This is fine if there are only a couple of links, but recently one of my main clients seems to be including every social media link under the sun to their designs so doing it this way can be a bit clunky.

Is there a way I can combine everything into a `foreach` or something?

Comment: Using foreach would mean using an array as well - so think about what kind of data structure could be handy for doing this.

Comment: Is there something common to all of these statements? Are only small parts of these statements *variable*? Can you replace these statements with one statement with appropriate *variables* and a loop...?

Comment: @deceze the only parts that are different in each statement is the option value (twitter, facebook, instagram) and then the accompanying `li` class and link `href`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if you mean exactly that, but check this code:

```
foreach(array('twitter', 'facebook', 'instagram') as $source)
    {
    $data = of_get_option($source);
    if($data)
        {
        echo '<li class="'.$source.'"><a href="'.$data.'">'.ucfirst($source).'</a></li>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, this should shave a few minutes off my development time in the future +1

Comment: I edited this code inside SO window, not in my IDE. Removed any excessive whitespace - thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Im refering to your indentation style (which is unchanged) - it's neither K&R, nor one-true-brace. Having the braces at a different indent to the block they belong to will (probably) advesely affect readability.

Comment: I use slighly modified version of Whitesmith's style (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Whitesmiths_style) without space after keywords (if, while, etc.). To be honest I developed it by myself while learning to code as I was 15-16 years old, only accidentally learned its name in early 20s. :)

Answer (score 6):

1. Identify commonalities:

   ```
   echo '<li class="twitter"><a href="'.$twt.'">Twitter</a></li>';
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```
2. Identify varying parts:

   ```
   echo '<li class="twitter"><a href="'.$twt.'">Twitter</a></li>';
                    ^^^^^^^                     ^^^^^^^
   ```
3. Identify dependencies and relationships:

   `$twt` depends on `of_get_option(...)` whose parameter is the same as the `twitter` in 2.
   The class and the name of the service are dependent on each other. Their relationship is apparently that the name is just the first-letter-uppercased version of the class, but I wouldn't rely on that necessarily.

Unify:

```
$services = array(
    'twitter'  => 'Twitter',
    'facebook' => 'Facebook'
    ...
);

foreach ($services as $service => $name) {
    if ($url = of_get_option($service)) {
        printf('<li class="%s"><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', $service, $url, $name);
        // or, if you can't be sure that the variables are safe for HTML interpolation:
        // printf('<li class="%s"><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', htmlspecialchars($service), htmlspecialchars($url), htmlspecialchars($name));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
$social_media = array(
    array( 'name' => 'Twitter', 'href' => of_get_option('twitter') ),
    array( 'name' => 'Facebook', 'href' => of_get_option('facebook') ),
    array( 'name' => 'Instagram', 'href' => of_get_option('instagram') )
);

foreach( $social_media as $s )
    echo '<li class="' . strtolower( $s["name"] ) . '"><a href="' . $s["href"] . '">' . $s["name"] . '</a></li>';
```

Then simply add the new social media site into the `$social_media` array.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$social = array('Twitter', 'Facebook', 'Instagram');

for($i=0;$i<length($social); ++$i) {
    $twt = of_get_option($social[$i]);
    if ($twt) {
        echo '<li class="' . strtolower($social[$i]) . '"><a href="' . $twt . '">' . $social[$i].     '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

You can add additional social networks by adding them to the array. It's a compact solution.